# Node.JS LinkedIn login/authentication WITHOUT Express? All back end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm quite new with Node.JS, OAuth, and the LinkedIn API, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to build a backend application that will read data from LinkedIn and store it in a database.  This will have no front end interaction.  I need to be able to get an access token, authenticate, and read data.

Unfortunately, all of the tutorials that I have found use Express, which makes them web apps. I don't want a web app - I want a backend application. Is this even possible, given that LinkedIn requires the use of callback URLs?  (I'm not sure how I would capture the callback without Express.)

I would greatly appreciate any current working examples, tutorials, APIs, or other assistance.

Comment: Asking for examples or other off-site is frowned-upon here. Also, the question is kind of vague and I'm not clear if you will have one account the server uses to authenticate, multiple, etc.  But now that I'm done nagging, check out [node-oauth](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth) and you can find more if you search for "nodejs oauth client"...  :)

Comment: My apologies.  I wasn't aware that asking for examples or other off-site is frowned upon.  I thought I had seen these type of questions before.  I will keep this in mind for the future.  That being said, thank you very much for your response.  I believe this is just what I was looking for!

Comment: No problems.  I think there should be a way to ask for off-site advice but the site isn't engineered for that.  See #4 on [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) where it's described as a "bad" question.  I suspect the problem is really because these are often very subjective questions, rather than very specific "here's the bug" things...